# Sheetsee - inserting variables in sql statement with sheetsee

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

For some reason I cant get the below mentioned query to work with sheetsee and google spreadsheets. It's most probably me.... but I can really need someone to please help me out here?

Many thanks in advance!
Robert

---

```
// spreadsheet URL.
var PARTICIPANTS = KEY

// Load Sessions per client
var client = 'C005';

$('#sessions-clients').sheetrock({
    url: PARTICIPANTS,
    sql: "select N where B = " + $client +"",
    headers: 1,
    headersOff: false,
    formatting: true,
    labels: ['Projects']
});
```

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean?

Comment: the sql part where I want to have the "where" clause use the var=client. I cannot get the syntax to work with a Google Spreadsheet query that's using the client variable.

Comment: I guess you already tried `sql: "select N where B = " + $client + "", ...`

Comment: Afraid so... same non-result. :(

Comment: Maybe this example can help: https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock/issues/24 ... from this I would say your string has to look like this: `"select N where B = '"+ $client + "'"`

Comment: :) Ta-daa! Thx mate! Not quite like that, but got it to work with: "select E where B = '"+ client + "'".

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer, so this can be of use to others:

I found an [example](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock/issues/24) in the web, where the string goes like this:

```
sql: "select %Name%," + columnLabel + " where " + columnLabel + " contains 'X'"
```

So my guess was it has to be

```
"select N where B = '"+ $client + "'"
```

But in fact user2523051 found out that the **correct answer** is:

```
"select E where B = '"+ client + "'" //<- without the "$"
```